# Kotlin: Generic Iterator over Enum: how to declare type variables

Tags: generics, enums, kotlin

My (non compiling) code for a generic iterator over enumerations is as follows:

```
class EnumIterator<T: Enum<T>>: Iterator<T> 
{
   private var cursor = 0

   override fun hasNext(): Boolean = cursor < enumValues<T>().size - 1
   override fun next(): T = enumValues<T>()[cursor++]
}
```

The IntelliJ IDE marks the *T* in both *enumValues< T >* red:

> "Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead."

How to declare the type parameters to get rid of the error?

Comment: To confirm, you want to get an Iterator<T>, where T is an enum type, which has its values iterated over?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Without reified type

```
enum class Example {
    A, B, C, D
}

fun <T: Enum<T>> iterator(values:()->Array<T>):Iterator<T> = values()
    .asIterable()
    .iterator()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val iterator = iterator(Example::values)

    iterator.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

This works by using a function instead of a wrapper class, depending on your use it may be a better option.

### With reified type

```
enum class Example {
    A, B, C, D
}

inline fun <reified T: Enum<T>> iterator():Iterator<T> = enumValues<T>().iterator()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val iterator = iterator<Example>()

    iterator.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

This requires the type to be explicitly set, but does not need a reference to the values method.

Comment: Might as well simplify to `fun <T> iterator(values: Array<T>):Iterator<T>` and `iterator(Example.values())`.

Comment: `enumValues<T>().iterator()` instead of `T::class.java.enumConstants.iterator()`?

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to pass the class into the constructor explicitly (and can have a factory function to avoid it at the call-site):

```
class EnumIterator<T: Enum<T>>(clazz: Class<T>): Iterator<T> {
   private var cursor = 0
   // your original code gets them on each hasNext/next call
   private val values = clazz.enumConstants

   override fun hasNext(): Boolean = cursor < values.size - 1
   override fun next(): T = values[cursor++]
}

// factory function 
inline fun <reified T: Enum<T>> EnumIterator(): EnumIterator<T> = EnumIterator(T::class.java)
```

You can also slightly simplify this if you don't need `EnumIterator` as a separate type by making it local (EDIT: @jrtapsell's "With reified type" solution is better):

```
inline fun <reified T: Enum<T>> EnumIterator(): Iterator<T> = object : Iterator<T> {
    private var cursor = 0
    private val values = enumValues<T>()

    override fun hasNext(): Boolean = cursor < values.size - 1
    override fun next(): T = values[cursor++]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`enumValues` is an inline function so the exact type of its reified parameter must be known at compile time which is impossible in your case.

Why not just do `AnyEnumClass.values().iterator()` if you need an iterator.

Comment: It is impossible with this exact code, the question is how to make it possible.